# WP Rewrite for a custom variable

Tags: url-rewriting

I know there are dozens of posts on this, but (I'm embarassed to say this) I'm having a rough time following them.

My goal here is to have `/resources?audience=teachers` become `/resources/audience/teachers` or event `/resources/teachers`.

I have 2 custom taxonomies on attachments - Types and Audiences. I then have a page titled Resources which is going to house all of the attachments within these categories. If an audience of type is specified, I will only display that term's attachments.

I've tried using the following this within an `init` hook:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'resources/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=resources&audience=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
```

With no success. I'm sure it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'resources/audience/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=resources&audience=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
```

in your `init` hook.

Then you should add your own query variable:

```
function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'audience';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');
```

Then flush rewrite rules (go to permalink settings and push "save" button).

After visiting url: `site.com/resources/audience/teachers/` your recources page should be shown. You can get value of `audience` variable with `get_query_var()` function.

Comment: That's great! How would you force `/resources/?audience=teachers` to show up as `/resources/audience/teachers` the way `/?p=123` redirects to `/post-slug` ?

Comment: Force to show where? You hardcoded this link, I guess, so you have to change it yourself. It isn't link to any existing WordPress object, so WordPress won't generate these links for you.

Comment: Actually I created it using add_query_arg( 'audience', 'teachers' ) which doesn't handle the rewrite. How would you utilize WP functions to create the rewritten version?

Comment: `add_query_arg` adds query argument (tada ;)). If you don't wont to add it as query argument and wat to create link in some format, just do it ;) (append it to the link)